# Homomorphism between two metric spaces. Then choose the correct option

Tags: general-topology

let $f : ( X , d_1) \rightarrow (Y, d_2)$  be  a homeomorphism  between  two metric spaces. Then choose the correct option

$1. f(A)$  is  bounded  subset of $Y$ , whenever  $A$ is  a    bounded  subset of $X$.

$2.$ $f (A^{\circ}) = (f (A))^{\circ}$ , for  $A \subseteq X$, where $A^{\circ}$  denote the interior  of $A$

$3.$ $f(\bar A) = \overline{f(A)}$ for $A \subseteq X$, where  $\bar A$denotes the closure  of $A$

$4$.$d_1(x,y) =  d_2(f(x), f(y))$ for all $x, y \in X$

My attempt : I take $ (X, d_1)= (X, d_2) =  (\mathbb{R} , d)$  where $d= |x-y|$

Then i thinks  option $1$ is false  take  $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ but A = $\mathbb{R}$  which unbounded set

For option $2$ is true ,take  $f(x) = x$ where $x= \mathbb{Q}$ we know that $\mathbb{Q}^{\circ}= \phi$

option $3$ is false take  $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$ where $A= \mathbb{N}$

option $4$ is true by definition of metric space

Is  its true ?

Comment: Did you mean homEomorphism?

Comment: yes  sir @DanielWainfleet i edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homeomorphism between two metric spaces simply means their topology is same. Options 1 and 4 are false as they are based on metric properties. Option 4 is the condition for isometry.  Under homeomorphism, the properties will be preserved which are described in terms of open sets and not in terms of distance.

Comment: how  do u discard option 2, 3

Comment: 2 and 3 are correct. These are standard results. See http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-closure-of-a-set-under-homeomorphisms-on-topological-spa and this http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-interior-of-a-set-under-homeomorphisms-on-topological-sp

Comment: Theorems which are valid for topological spaces automatically hold in metric spaces. But not conversely.

Comment: okss @Skylark thanks u

Comment: You should edit your answer. You say that option 2 is false in the answer, but then in the comments say option 2 is correct. Overall, options 1 and 4 are false and 2 and 3 are true.

Comment: @NicholasRoberts Yes thank you .. That was a dangerous typo!